# Error when validating float value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to validate a float value called total in my code. When entering the form, I have entered 11000.00 in the textbox. I submitted the form and it says total must be number.

This is my controller

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
                'voucher_no' => ['required', Rule::unique('comparisonsuppliers', 'voucher_no')],
                'supplier'=> ['required'],
                'last_revised'=> ['required'],
                'sources'=> ['required'],
                'total'=>'required|numeric|between:0,999999.99',
                'remark'=> ['required'],
                'credit_term'=> ['required'],
                'delivery_period'=> ['required'],
            ]);

            comparisonsuppliers::insert($validatedData);

            return response()->json('Form is successfully validated and data has been saved.');
```

Comment: could you please share yout request , dd();

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like ..

```
'total' => 'required|regex:/^\d*(\.\d{2})?$/'
```

Comment: If you give an answer, always try to explain it, do not just say "Do this" or "Try this". Thanks